# how do i use pointers for storing multiple strings using malloc

Tags: c, string, pointers, malloc, file-handling

I tried to make a program to dynamically allocate memory for storing multiple strings using pointers but it cant seem to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int num;

    printf("enter no of students");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    char *names = (char*) malloc(num * 100 * sizeof(char));

    printf("enter the names");
    fp = fopen("file.txt","w");

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        fgets(*(names + i * 100), 100, stdin);
        fprintf(fp, "%s\n", (names + i * 100));
    }

    fclose(fp);

    fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    printf("names stored in *ptr");
}
```

Comment: you are allocating one array only. I believe you needed a `char **names` variable, and then allocate 100 arrays of 100 spaces... Or, you could reuse the array when reading the input...

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a table of the pointers to the char.

```
char **strtable = NULL
size_t nstrings = 0; 

int addstring(const char *str)
{
    int result = -1;
    char **tmp = realloc(strtable, (nstrings + 1)* sizeof(*strtable));

    if(tmp)
    {
        tmp[nstrings] = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
        if(tmp[nstrings])
        {
            result = 0;
            strtable = tmp;
            strcpy(tmp[nstrings++], str);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Using it you can add the entered (read) strings and easy iterate.

Comment: He knows the number of students so he doesn't have to inefficiently realloc on each call: `scanf("%d",&num);`. Neither does he need a separate function to do that: just incorporate it in his `main`.

Comment: `strlen(string)` ==> `strlen(str)`

Comment: @PaulOgilvie 1. I am showing him the way, not giving the most efficient code on the planet. BTW efficiency of realloc in this case is less than marginal. 2. C is the procedural language and it is a very bad habit to incorporate everything in main. Maybe your programs have a massive 50000 lines main and no functions at all, but it is not the example to follow. I consider your comment as a nitpick

Comment: @4386427 Yes  you right, SO could eventually have a normal code editor. It is time to move to the 21st century

Comment: @P__J__ Not sure why you write that comment to me. I don't do the SO UI. I just helped you improve your answer.

Comment: @P__J__ If it was a general remark, why did you tag it for me?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the answer above but if you want to keep the same structure there you go

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<conio.h>
    void main()
    {
    FILE *fp;
    int num;

    printf("enter no of students ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    char *names=malloc(num*100);


    printf("enter the names\n");
    fp=fopen("file.txt","w");
                fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);

    for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
    {

    fgets((names + i * 100), 100, stdin);
    fprintf(fp, "%s", (names + i * 100));
        fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    fp=fopen("file.txt","r");
    printf("names stored in *ptr");
    fclose(fp);
    }
```

Comment: 1) Please indent the code properly. 2) Why use `fseek`?

Comment: I used fseek to clear the stdin buffer properly after the first input 'num'

Answer (score 1):

You've got several problems. Firstly `scanf` doesn't play nicely with `fgets` - it'll leave a the newline in the input stream which means when you call `fgets` it'll just read that. Easiest way to fix that is to use `fgets` to read in the whole line when asking for the number of students and `sscanf` to get the actual number like this:

```
char temp[100];
fgets(temp,100,stdin);
sscanf(temp,"%d",&num);
```

Secondly, you're only creating one really big long string, rather than multiple strings. So to create `num` strings you first want to allocate the "array" of strings like this

```
names=malloc(sizeof(char *)*num);
```

and then use a loop to allocate the space for the strings

```
for(int i=0; i<num; i++)
{
     names[i]=malloc(100);
}
```

You'll also see don't need to cast the return value from `malloc`, but you do need to include the right file, namely "stdlib.h". And technically you don't need `sizeof(char)` as that'll always be 1.

You don't check the return values from `fopen` so you don't handle the situation where it cannot open the file for writing.

Not sure why you're also opening the file for reading at the end either as you don't do anything with it and it'll just get closed automatically when the program ends.

And you should always get into the habit of writing the code to free your allocated memory even if you don't need to cos the code is this simple.

Also technically `main` should return `int`.

Final version of the code could look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int num;
    char temp[100];

    printf("enter no of students");
    fgets(temp,100,stdin);
    sscanf(temp,"%d",&num);
    char **names=malloc(num*sizeof(char*));


    printf("enter the names");
    fp=fopen("file.txt","w");
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to open\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        names[i]=malloc(100);
        fgets(names[i],100,stdin);
        fprintf(fp,"%s\n",names[i]);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    for(int i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        free(names[i]);
    }
    free(names);

    printf("names stored in *ptr");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is to declare `names` as "a pointer to an array of 100 char" and use just a single malloc. After that you can simply access the individual name using `names[i]`.

Like this:

```
char (*names)[100] = malloc(num * sizeof *names);

printf("enter the names\n");
fp = fopen("file.txt","w");

for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    fgets(names[i], 100, stdin);
    fprintf(fp, "%s", names[i]);
}

fclose(fp);
```

A few extra comments:

1) `sizeof(char)` is always 1

2) Notice that `scanf("%d",&num);` will leave a newline in the input buffer. That causes your first name to be empty. You need to remove that newline before scanning names

3) Also notice that `fgets` will include a newline (at least when the input is less than 99 chars).

4) It seems that you don't really need to store all names in array as you write them to the file immediately. So you could simply do:

```
printf("enter the names\n");
fp = fopen("file.txt","w");

for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    char name[100];
    fgets(name, 100, stdin);
    fprintf(fp, "%s", name);
}

fclose(fp);
```